# BDD/DDD: Feature File that cross boundaries

Tags: domain-driven-design, bdd, user-stories, bounded-contexts

Im working on an App which deals with Short Courses, basically a Customer can register or reserve a course, buy books or other materials needed for the course(miscellaneous).

The use case is:

```
As a sales person
I need to record customers orders (reservation, registration, miscellaneous)
So that I can keep track of each slots needed
```

But when discussing with the domain experts.

```
Lets say the customer orders
1 English Course Registration which costs 499
1 Translation Course Registration which costs 899
1 Reservation for HR Resource 899
1 Book which cost 250

Then
I should have
1 Order containing all the 4 items (2 course, 1 reservation, 1 book) including the prices.

1 course registration for English  (includes the Order No., unique Registration No.)
1 course registration for Translation (includes the Order No., unique Registration No.)
1 reservation form. (includes the Order No. and unique Reservation No.)
```

(The registration has Registration No., and ORder No. for reference as well as course title, date, venue)

**Please take note that we allow partial payment.**

Im treating `Sales Order` as separate bounded context and `Registration & Reservation Bounded Context` as another one

But based on the use case which **crosses boundaries**, does it mean that the two contexts should be merged?

Answer (score 2):

Strictly speaking, a bounded context is only bounded by the use of the Ubiquitous Language - that is, you get a hint that you need a new bounded context when you discover the same word having a slightly different meaning when used by different people or at different times.

In this case, it would be worth exploring weather or not a 'registration' in the context of a sales person recording a customer order is the *same thing* as a registration in the context of somebody reserving a place in a course.

And by *same thing* I don't mean the very same registration, I mean - in each context, does it behave the same way? Are the same properties important?

If the answer is yes - then perhaps you are really looking at the same bounded context.  But it's also possible that you are looking at the same *thing* represented in different ways in different bounded contexts.

This is actually the most freeing part of using separate bounded contexts:

1. In the Sales Order context you can model a registration exactly how it needs to be modelled in order to make it part of an order.
2. In the Registration & Reservation context you can model a registration exactly how it needs to be modelled to reserve places and confirm attendance (I assume).

As long as you pick a way of uniquely identifying a registration that allows you to correlate registrations in the two contexts - and an integration strategy (e.g. REST API, or asynchronous messaging) that allows you to coordinate long running workflows that span contexts - aka a [saga](https://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2013/03/14/saga-implementation-patterns-controller/), that's perfectly fine.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that BC should be a boundary on UL. I think the sales part is like an aggregator of things that we sell on different bounded context  so we only need the description and price of the item. like in the Course List BC for reservation (list of courses that we offer without the specific dates yet, only the standard price and duration), Course Calendar BC for registration (courses that are scheduled on specific date and venue), and other sellable items like books etc (Miscellaneous). While on the Registration BC we dont need the price anymore or even miscellaneous items.

Comment: Since our company is small, The challenging part for me is that one person from our company is working on multiple departments playing different roles which requires different  data which kinda confuses me whether we are at the same context or already discussing another context.